# Is there a file in Windows XP that tells you which Printers and maybe which Map Network drives you have?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a file in Windows XP that tells you which Printers and maybe which Map Network drives you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no preset file that I know of, but you can create a file with the list of mapped network drives with the following command:

`net use >drives.txt`

This will create a file called `drives.txt` with the information.

If you want this file to be automatically updated, you can create a scheduled task to do it for you.

Edit: For printers, try this:

`cscript //Nologo %windir%\system32\prnmngr.vbs -l >printers.txt`

Comment: Any way to do this for the printers?

Comment: I updated my answer to include printers.

Comment: Did I mention you are amazing?

Answer (score 2):

You are specifically looking for a file? Or simply finding out whether you have either of these things? On your own machine? If so, uhm. . ., it is as simple as double clicking My Computer and seeing your Mapped Drives there. It will appear under "Network Drives".

But if you are seeking this information to export and import:

Try this at [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/27/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares.aspx).

and this for printers:

A tool at Microsoft.com, search for Print Migrator 3.1. Sorry I can't post a second link because I am new.

Hope these help.

Comment: Or, if you are looking to see which shares are accessible on your own machine you can run:

    %systemroot%\system32\fsmgmt.msc